# Django Attribute Error: object has not attribute 'forms'

Tags: python, django, django-intermediate-table

I have a model formset of an intermediate model that I am using to assign users to another model. When I try to generate the view I get `'StaffAssignmentForm' object has no attribute 'forms'`.

Model

```
class StaffAssignment(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, related_name='study_set', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='assigned_to_set', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    assigned_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-role',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is assigned to {}'.format(self.staff, self.study)
```

The form

```
class AddStaff(forms.ModelForm):
    model = StaffAssignment
    fields = ('staff',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddStaff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            for field in form.fields:
                form.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

The View

```
def add_staff(request, study_slug):
    study = get_object_or_404(Study, slug=study_slug)
    staff_formset = modelformset_factory(StaffAssignment, form=AddStaff, fields=('staff',), extra=5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        staffList = staff_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if staffList.is_valid():
            for assignment in staffList:
                assigned = assignment.save(commit=False)
                assigned.study = study
                assigned.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studies:studydashboard'))
        else:
            pass
    else:
        staffList = staff_formset(queryset=StaffAssignment.objects.none())
        return render(request, 'studies/addstaff.html', {'staffList': staffList, 'study': study})
```

The Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/studies/add-staff/lilly-a4/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'studies',
 'account')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/RickyD/PycharmProjects/StudyTrack/studies/templates/studies/addstaff.html, error at line 20
   'StaffAssignmentForm' object has no attribute 'forms'

   10 : {% block content %}
   11 :     <div class="row">
   12 :         <div class="col-md-8">
   13 :         <div class="box box-primary">
   14 :             <div class="box-header with-border">
   15 :                 <h3 class="box-title">Add new study </h3>
   16 :             </div>
   17 :             <form action="{% url 'studies:addstaff' study.slug %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   18 :                 {% csrf_token %}
   19 :                 <div class="box-body">
   20 :                      {{ staffList.as_p }} 
   21 :                 </div>
   22 :                 <div class="box-footer">
   23 :                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   24 :                 </div>
   25 :             </form>
   26 :         </div>
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     </div>
   29 : 
   30 :     <div class="col-md-4">

Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/RickyD/PycharmProjects/StudyTrack/studies/views.py" in add_staff
  87.         return render(request, 'studies/addstaff.html', {'staffList': staffList, 'study': study})
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  210.                     return self._render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  202.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  905.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  89.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  648.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  789.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  849.                             current = current()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in as_p
  406.         forms = ' '.join(form.as_p() for form in self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in __iter__
  73.         return iter(self.forms)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  59.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  142.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in <listcomp>
  142.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  596.         return super(BaseModelFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in _construct_form
  167.         form = self.form(**defaults)
File "/Users/RickyD/PycharmProjects/StudyTrack/studies/forms.py" in __init__
  69.         for form in self.forms:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /studies/add-staff/lilly-a4/
Exception Value: 'StaffAssignmentForm' object has no attribute 'forms'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating forms in your Form, but Form doesn't have any forms attribute.

```
class AddStaff(forms.ModelForm):
    model = StaffAssignment
    fields = ('staff',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddStaff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #for form in self.forms:
        #for field in form.fields:
        for field in self.fields:
           self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```